# Ocaml unboud value

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to write a simple Ocaml function but im getting this error:

Error: This expression has type unit
       but an expression was expected of type int

```
let rec euclid a b = 
  if a = b then a
  else if a < b then 1
  else if a > b then 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the immediate problem, you need `else` clauses in your function:

```
let rec euclid a b =
  if a = b then a
  else if a < b then 1
  else 2 (* You know a > b is the only possible alternative *)
```

You may realize this, but this function is not recursive, nor, I think, is it doing what you want it to do.

However, there is an error in the way you're conceptualizing how a function works in Ocaml. The way you've written the function is imperative in nature; it is a series of `if/then` statements which are acted upon sequentially. Rather, the return value of `euclid` should be simply the result of one broad `if/then` statement (an integer value). Nesting, as I have done above, can be acceptable, but the essential thing to take away is that a function is just a single expression which is evaluated, not a series of imperative actions.

**EDIT** for updated question:

All OCaml `if/then` statements should have `else` clauses. Your very last nested `if/then` statement has no `else` clause. If OCaml detects an `if/then` statement with no `else` clause, an `else` clause is assumed returning `()` (unit). Essentially, if `a > b` is false, what should OCaml return? It assumes nothing, but returning `()` conflicts with the supposed type of your function (an integer).

Of course, that `a > b` is false is impossible in your function, since if not `a = b` and not `a < b`, the only other choice is `a > b`. Thus, you don't need another `if` statement at the end of your function; at that point, you know without a doubt that `a > b`, so you can simply say `else 2`.